# What does this eclipse error mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class    [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] for bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in    class path resource [spring_hibernate.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:910)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.App.main(App.java:14)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
... 9 more
```

**Class**

```
package com;

  import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
     import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

        import com.entity.Ws_security;
     import com.services.Interface_ws_security_services;

    public class App {

private static ApplicationContext ctx1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ctx1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_hibernate.xml");

    Interface_ws_security_services service=(Interface_ws_security_services) ctx1.getBean("a");

    Ws_security ess=new Ws_security();
    ess.setIDws("ess1");
    ess.setLogin("ess2");
    service.addws(ess);
    System.out.println("Done");


      }

        }
```

**Config file for Spring Hibernate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">



       <context:component-scan base-package="java.com" />
       <context:annotation-config />

       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
       <bean id="transactionManager"  
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />  
    </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/webservices" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
  </bean>



<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="java.com" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

I am using Maven, Spring and Hibernate.  I do not understand this problem. I try to insert some data to my database, but my project does not work.

Answer (score 3):

It is clearly telling in the exception trace: 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`

So you are missing `spring orm` jar file in your classpath, add it in your class path and retest it.

If you are using maven then add this dependency into your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Correct spring `<version>` tag value depending on your spring version.

Comment: i add this jar but i have another error [Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [spring_hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring_hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE]

Comment: give us whole stack trace.

Comment: 'Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring_hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE'

Comment: is that all? it does not say much things.

Comment: can y send me y mail because the error is long , i can't write it in comment

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847705/please-help-me-i-could-understand-this-error] this the second error please

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the spring orm jar file to your class path. To do this add the jar file to the workspace. Next right click on your project and select properties. Then go to the side tab "Java build path" then the top tab "Libraries" then press "Add jars" and navigate to the location of the jar file.

Comment: i use maven so  i just need to add dependency for this jar